Application sends window to local machine with X11, rather than remote desktop on VM
I am connecting to a VM using PuTTY to set up a ssh tunnel with port forwarding so I can then connect to a remote desktop using RDP. I'm starting on Windows and landing on Ubuntu 22.04 with xrdp and xfce4.
For some reason, when I open a windowed application on the remote desktop via the remote terminal (i.e. the one you open from the RDP), the application doesn't open in the remote desktop, but instead tries to send the window to an X server. If I add X11 forwarding to the ssh tunnel connection, then the application opens in a window on my local machine. If I don't have X11 forwarding, then the application crashes saying it can't find a display.
Why is this happening, and how can I get it to open on the remote desktop?

After a fair bit of trial and error, I discovered the root cause of this behaviour was the fact that I had logged into a different user account using sudo su to run the application.
When I copied the application to the user account that I used to login to the RDP session, the application opened in a Window on the RDP.
For some reason, logging in to a different user account this way wants to forward windows to X11.
